# Оборот с союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу понять, используется ли здесь оборот с "как" в значении "подобно" или в значении "в качестве" и, соответственно, надо ли ставить запятую или нет?

Вставка из инконеля на кольце диска при закрытии ведет себя упруго как мягкое уплотнение, обеспечивая дополнительную герметичность, в том числе для криогенных и других очень летучих сред.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна. У вас получилось уточнение. Не было бы "упруго" – не было бы запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

Вставка из инконеля на кольце диска при закрытии ведет себя упруго, как мягкое уплотнение, обеспечивая дополнительную герметичность, в том числе для криогенных и других очень летучих сред.

Здесь обособленный сравнительный оборот в роли второго (пояснительного) именного сказуемого: вставка ведет себя упруго; ведет себя как мягкое уплотнение.

Comment: София, при обособлении получится перечислительная интонация.вседет себя и упруго и как мягкое уплотнение, или, что еще хуже : подобно уплотнению. Что уже несуразно.

Comment: Мягкое уплотнение (резиновое) ведет себя упруго, вставка из инконеля тоже ведет себя упруго, она по свойствам сходна с мягким уплотнением. Я так понимаю смысл предложения, и именно такой смысл выражает его грамматика при наличии обособления.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь технический текст, где неуместны сравнения. Здесь: в значении " в качестве".

Comment: А может быть это составная часть сказуемого? "ведет себя упруго как мягкое уплотнение"
Но в любом случае запятая не ставится. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Вы правы.